# How to get last onPause fragment trigger?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, android-lifecycle

I have activity which contain 3 fragment.
when the activity onPaused the 3 fragment set a value to a variable.

I want to check that var in the onPause activity.

but the problem that `onPause` activity called first and then the fragment `onPause` called.

How to solve that ?

so i need to run a function when all onPause function finish running ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could define an interface in your fragment and make the activity implement that interface. Then define one method like `variableWasSet()` in that interface and call it in `onPause()` in your fragment **after** you set your variable. That's a recommended way for [communication between fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).

Or use an event bus system for communication between fragments and activities. 
Like [otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) or [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

Comment: thank you for your answer. the first approach will call onPause mutliple times, so it's not suite my needs .regarding to second approach: i will have look at this.

Comment: I guess this happens because you have 3 instances of the same fragment? Using an event bus cause the same effect then. If you indeed have 3 instances then you would have to handle this yourself by checking if 'something' was already done.

Comment: actually i have more than 3 instances. and the number of fragments are changed according to the user activities. so it will be a little bit difficult to handle that. thank you for your time